# Identify first group of two consecutive numbers in data frame by group

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable

I have a data frame (testdf_long) with 1632 obs. of 3 variables (year, model, and value). Here are the first 34 rows of the data frame:

```
year      model                            value
<chr>     <chr>                            <dbl>
1 2015-2020 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     0
2 2020-2025 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     0
3 2025-2030 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     0
4 2030-2035 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     0
5 2035-2040 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     1
6 2040-2045 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     1
7 2045-2050 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     1
8 2050-2055 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     1
9 2055-2060 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126     0
10 2060-2065 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126    1
11 2065-2070 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126    1
12 2070-2075 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126    1
13 2075-2080 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126    1
14 2080-2085 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126    1
15 2085-2090 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126    1
16 2090-2095 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126    1
17 2095-2100 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126    1
18 2015-2020 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 0
19 2020-2025 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 0
20 2025-2030 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
21 2030-2035 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
22 2035-2040 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
23 2040-2045 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
24 2045-2050 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 0
25 2050-2055 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
26 2055-2060 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
27 2060-2065 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
28 2065-2070 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 0
29 2070-2075 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
30 2075-2080 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
31 2080-2085 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
32 2085-2090 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
33 2090-2095 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
34 2095-2100 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126 1
```

The value column is binary where 1 indicates that a critical temperature value was exceeded, and 0 indicates the temperature is below that critical value.

I would like to identify the *first time* there are *at least* two consecutive 5-year bins where the critical temperature is exceeded (the value == 1 in *at least* two consecutive rows) for each model. There are 96 models in total, and I am showing the first 2 models here.

My desired output would be something like:

```
2035-2040 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126
2025-2030 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126
```

A follow-up question:  If instead of binary values, I have yearly temperature in the value column, is there a way to extract the time when a critical temperature value was first exceeded for a minimum of, for example, 5 or 10 years (5 or 10 rows)?

For instance, I have a data frame with 255 obs. of 3 variables (year, scenario, and value). Here are the first 36 rows, showing the temperature change up to 2050 for one scenario for a particular location. In the actual data frame I have data from 2015-2099 for three scenarios (ssp126, ssp245, and ssp370).

```
 Year scenario      value 
1   2015   ssp126 0.16344980
2   2016   ssp126 0.44860960
3   2017   ssp126 1.04100200
4   2018   ssp126 0.51012240
5   2019   ssp126 0.82980580
6   2020   ssp126 0.56152220
7   2021   ssp126 0.88473630
8   2022   ssp126 0.69088860
9   2023   ssp126 0.70459570
10  2024   ssp126 0.72352020
11  2025   ssp126 1.15073200
12  2026   ssp126 1.06018500
13  2027   ssp126 0.66827390
14  2028   ssp126 0.93438720
15  2029   ssp126 0.76251340
16  2030   ssp126 1.28453400
17  2031   ssp126 0.96820190
18  2032   ssp126 1.04495400
19  2033   ssp126 1.32369400
20  2034   ssp126 0.98371650
21  2035   ssp126 1.04871200
22  2036   ssp126 1.54639300
23  2037   ssp126 1.42122500
24  2038   ssp126 1.37967200
25  2039   ssp126 1.18178500
26  2040   ssp126 1.25387600
27  2041   ssp126 1.51820400
28  2042   ssp126 1.64834500
29  2043   ssp126 1.58128900
30  2044   ssp126 1.50273300
31  2045   ssp126 1.58439500
32  2046   ssp126 1.28165400
33  2047   ssp126 1.74803400
34  2048   ssp126 1.49539300
35  2049   ssp126 1.73268000
36  2050   ssp126 1.60527000
```

Let's say the critical temperature change is 1 deg C for this location. I would like to extract when that value is first exceeded for 5 or 10 consecutive years. In this case the temperature is first >1C for both 5 or 10 consecutive years in 2035.

My desired output would be something like:

```
21  2035   ssp126 1.04871200 (plus the same info for the 2 other scenarios, ssp245 and ssp370).
```

This data frame also only represents the temperature information from one location. I have a large list of data frames with the same information for ~300 locations (by ID). I would also like to apply the critical temperature exceedance code to that list. Each location (ID) has a different critical temperature (t_crit) stored in a separate data frame. For example, the first five rows look like:

```
   ID t_crit
1   RGI60-01.11045   2.23
2   RGI60-01.11042   1.09
3   RGI60-01.11036   4.44
4   RGI60-01.11032   4.99
5   RGI60-01.10917   1.95
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to simply `filter` where the `value` is 1 as well as the `lead` (following row) `value` is also 1. Then, if grouped by `model`, you can `slice(1)` to get the first row/occurrence for a given `model`.

```
library(tidyverse)

testdf_long %>%
  group_by(model) %>%
  filter(value == 1 & lead(value) == 1) %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Output**

```
  year      model                               value
  <chr>     <chr>                               <int>
1 2035-2040 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126        1
2 2025-2030 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126     1
```

---

With respect to the second question, you can use the `zoo` package with `rollapply` for convenience. This will do a rolling look at your data, and you can specify `width` of 5 or 10 for the window, and use `all` as function to keep where true. Then, since the data are grouped by `scenario`, you can use `slice` to keep the first value where true.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(scenario) %>%
  filter(rollapply(value > 1, width = 5, all, align = "left", fill = F) == T) %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Output**

```
   Year scenario value
  <int> <chr>    <dbl>
1  2035 ssp126    1.05
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. If instead of binary values, I have the yearly temperature in the value column, is there a way to extract when a critical temperature value was exceeded for a minimum of 10 years (or 10 rows?). Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that! I've just revised.

Comment: @LauraLarocca See edited answer for the second question - hope this helps. As for your list of data.frames, would make this a separate post/question on SO, and give an example.

Answer (score 0):

If your data set name is `df` then ,

```
newdf <- df %>% group_by(model) %>% mutate(cumval = cumsum(value))

newdf[which(newdf$cumval == 2)-1 ,][1:2]

# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   model [2]
  year      model                              
  <chr>     <chr>                               
1 2035-2040 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.CM2_ssp126        
2 2025-2030 RGI60.01.01854_ACCESS.ESM1.5_ssp126
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this would work if you then filtered rows where the cumvalue equals 1 followed by 2.